# Use jquery on with keyevent

Tags: dom, jquery, onkeyup

I have a ajax function witch gets triggered by the .on function of jquery it looks like this:

```
//button handler
$('body').on('click', '#btn', function() {
    ajaxloader(this);
});
```

Now if I have a button and I give it the btn id it works all fine. How to do the same with the enter key-event. My pseudo code:

```
//key handler
$('body').on('onkeyup:13', '.enter', function() {
    ajaxloader(this);
});
```

I want to use it in the same context of the .on function but if this is not possible an other way will only work when I can pas the this variable form the element with the .enter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $('body').on('keyup', '.enter', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        ajaxloader(this);
      }
    });
```

Comment: It looks good but it it not working when I pres enter it does nothing

Comment: It works. I have tested the code myself. Here, `.enter` means when you will press 'enter' key on an html element with class `enter`. I think you need it on the whole page, then use this one `$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        ajaxloader(this);
      }
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
$('#searchbox input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
     var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
     if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
       //Do something
     }
});
```

Comment: How to bind this to .on event, I use jquery 1.9.1 the bind function is gone!

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want..

```
 $('body').on('keyup', '.enter', function(event) {
     if (event.keyCode == '13') {  /// check if the keypressed is enter.. if yes...
           //do your stuff
        }
 });
```

Comment: `onkeyup` is not a valid jQuery event.

Comment: yup... thanks...got confused with javascript...changed it to jquery... :)hehe.... i think i need to go for a coffee now....:p

Answer (score 0):

with some inspiration of @Jashwant I found how to do it. I use this to get all the attributes of the button witch is clicked but when using enter it does not know witch element it needs so I now appoint an element manually like this:

```
$('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            ajaxloader($('.enter'));
        }   
});
```